# What is the best way to read a file that is being modified using copy-on-write?

Tags: filesystems

We have a file that contains data that always needs to be consistent. When it needs to be modified, `Process 1` creates a new file, writes the new file with the modifications, and uses `mv` to rename the new file to the old filename.

If we have another process, `Process 2`, that needs to read this file, how can we guarantee that it will always read a consistent file, i.e. a `mv` by `Process 1` during the read can't cause corrupt data?

Comment: Using a cooperative lock to protect the write operation?

Comment: is `mv` just an example or the actual case? it's important for the answer, as `mv` doesn't change the file content.

Comment: @rush I believe we use the 'rename' POSIX function, not literally 'mv', however we could use whatever mechanism we want.  The reading process will likely be a shell script.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ideally this should be done only relying on what file operations Linux guarantees to be atomic.  Managing IPC for something so simple doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Comment: @Chuu Using `flock` (or similar advisory locking mechanism) does not require IPC. The simplest solution would be to try `mkdir lockdir` and if that fails, wait a bit and try again (because the other process is current holding the lock). `mkdir` is atomic unless you're on NFS.

Comment: @Chuu please change the title to sth relevant. "copy-on-write" means sth completely different.

Answer (score 4):

You guarantee that by creating the new file on the same filesystem as the old file, and using the `rename(2)`[1] function which is guaranteed to be atomic.

On Unix filesystems, a `rename(2)` only acts on the directory entries, it will not affect any process which has an open handle to the inode pointed by the original dir entry; that process will continue to read from or write to the old file.

Usually, the `mv(1)` utility will just invoke `rename(2)`, but it may fall back to a remove + copy over or other dubious non-atomic operations in the case where the `rename(2)` fails.

Notice that two files being on the same filesystem may not guarantee that a `rename(2)` will succeed -- there are filesystems like `9pfs` which do not support a rename operation, so it has to be manufactured, one way or another.

[1] or even better, `renameat(2)` which prevents against the leading paths to the files being surreptitiously changed from another process, ie "symlink attacks".

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question.  The first process is doing this to atomically update the file, as described above.  But the second process is just a reader.

Comment: That makes no difference. That -- or coordinating *all*  the processes which are using the file with locks -- are the only ways to guarantee that it won't read garbage from it.

Comment: @Chuu If you already decided that it's perfectly safe to use `mv(1)`, and are just looking for a confirmation of it, I'm afraid I cannot help you with that. `mv(1)` is not safe. You can look at the [steps](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) described in the standard and reach your own conclusions.